# Segmentation fault on memcmp

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memcmp

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <string.h>


int cauta(const void *x, int n, int dim_el, const void *el)
{
  char *c = (char*) x;
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if(memcmp(c + i * dim_el, el, dim_el) == 0)
      return 1;
  }
  return -1;
}

int main()
{
  int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0};
  int k;
  k = cauta(a, sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(a[0]), a[0]);
  printf("%d", k);
  return 0;
}
```

The problem appears on the commented line. The function returns 1 if "el" exists in the "x" array . It's a simple, yet I don't understand exactly why it's a segmfault.

[Also, this is the call stack display when I tried debugging it line by line.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doPrZ.png)

Comment: Too incomplete to be able to help.

Comment: @iharob, sorry, I edited and put the complete code

Comment: Please review pointers math ;-)

Comment: Enable compiler warnings.

Comment: @AlexandruIonuţBujor Passing `a[0]` as last parameter doesn't make much sense. You should have another variable and pass it's **address** there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, the function parameters are

```
 int cauta(const void *x,int n,int dim_el,const void *el)
```

where `el` expects a `const void *`, whereas, while calling,

```
cauta(a,sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]),sizeof(a[0]),a[0]);
```

you passed `a[0]` which is an `int`.

You need to pass an address, like `&a[3]`, for example.

That said, `int main()` should be `int main(void)` to conform to the standards.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in an `int` *i.e.* `a[0]` into `cauta` as an `const void *` that's going to cause the error.